# Why can't I connect mongodb using node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have started my mongodb server and the software can actually connect it.
[Mongodb started image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jheCP.png)
[Error Gif](https://i.loli.net/2021/02/20/tBp4oziaxqUI2mk.gif)
My node js code is

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/chat", { useNewUrlParser: true }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and it give me the error

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 closed
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Web开发\fake-chatroom\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:439:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12)]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (D:\Web开发\fake-chatroom\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at D:\Web开发\fake-chatroom\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:562:14
    at D:\Web开发\fake-chatroom\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:995:11
    at callback (D:\Web开发\fake-chatroom\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:75:5)
    at D:\Web开发\fake-chatroom\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:101:9
    at _callback (D:\Web开发\fake-chatroom\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:328:7)
    at Connection.errorHandler (D:\Web开发\fake-chatroom\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:343:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Web开发\fake-chatroom\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:437:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12)
```

Comment: The default port for MongoDB is 27017, where does 28019 come from?

Comment: Sorry, my question gave a wrong code. I have corrected it but the error is still happened.

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the connection string?

Comment: Yes, my database opened on 27017. I can connect it in my software, but in NodeJS it went wrong.

Comment: Does changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` change anything?

Comment: The error still happened.. I upload a gif.

Comment: @JustinSun Are you able to write data using Robo3T?

Comment: Yes, I can write data using Robo3T

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Maybe node.js does not like Chinese characters in folder name. Try a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

From the image you posted, mongodb is listening on the default port, 27017. Your code is attempting to open a connection to port 28019 which is the cause of the error.

Use the default port number in your code:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/chat", { useNewUrlParser: true }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Sorry, my question gave a wrong code. I have corrected it but the error is still happened.